# MVC LazyInitializer Error Handling

Tags: model-view-controller, error-handling, custom-error-pages, lazy-initialization

I want to  have an error Page if My Aplication cannot connect  to Database.
But for now I have sth like this:
[image: LazyInitializer]

Then If I step over I have an error in Layout where I check if IsAuthenticated it also shows an error in

```
<li>@if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {@Html.ActionLink("Admin Panel", "Index", "Admin")}
```

But it only happens if I am logged in.

If I am not logged in then it only shows an error which I showed in Picture, 
Then if I click step over I get an error page in web browser which is a result I want to have.
Q: How to  get an error Page if Database is not connected  without going to VS10 to code view ?

I also have an error controller and it works for displaying error page if someone  types wrong www address.

Comment: Use try catch... and RedirectToAction

Comment: Try Global Exception filters. It will help you to handle all exceptions for application